# Current flow across a diode

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

Recently on a book i came across a problem-[image]

Here when calculating the current flow through the diode they didn't consider the voltage drop across the diode.If it is correct then what am i missing?

Comment: You are missing "assume the diode to be ideal".  Ideal diodes don't have any voltage drop.

Comment: What a silly problem, If diode is ideal ... Id = V/R1 => 10/50...

Comment: @Trevor I think it's a reasonable "trick question" to make sure that the student understands that no current will flow through R2 if there is a short-circuit.

Comment: @pipe Indeed. If nothing else it proves Thevenin's theorem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question:

```
Assume the diode to be ideal
```

There is no voltage drop across ideal diodes.

Comment: Which makes the whole problem rather silly.

Comment: Well the title of the question says "Current flow across a diode", so I believe we've entered the silly valley already at the title.

Comment: @HarrySvensson ya I was talking about the exercise in the book though, not the OPs question..

Answer (score 4):

Since ideal diode has no voltage drop and it is forward biased, it can be considered as a short. Thus R2 is shorted and the current flowing will be just : I = V/R1.